# Save asmx message

Tags: xml, vb.net, asmx

I have a legacy ASMX service running on vb.net and I am having issues with a particular client saying it's not working.  Is there a simple way that I can log his XML requests from within the method that is being called?  I need to be sure that it is his request that is missing nodes / data before I respond to him.

I have looked around, and there are various ways of "echoing" the xml that has been received, but I really need to log the XML received alongside other data from within the method into a database.

Comment: You can enable tracing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb885203(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: As good as this is, I need to tie it up to several other things from the same request and save to a DB.

As the method progresses, it then saves other items and I'd like it to be easy to follow.  I also have customer data being passed by the method, so I need to be able to encrypt the data prior to saving